# How to store non-JSON response into a Postman Environmental Variable

Tags: environment-variables, postman

In Postman, I am doing a GET request to obtain an OAuth token. In the API, the response gives me a login URL value where once decoded, I will then be re-directed to the 3rd party to then gain the token etc.

The API response however is not a JSON response. By default the value is a text response.
I am aware that to store a JSON value I would use syntax like the below:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("login_url", data.login_url);
```

But how would I store the value if the response is not a JSON?

[image: Postman]

Comment: use regular expression , responseBody has text

Comment: Use `pm.response.text()` to get the response as text, the use regex like @PDHide mentioned to filter the text and grab the URL value.